# Logical error - JSP and Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a list of 50 questions and request the user to answer any 25 questions of his choice. I am using JSP and Servlet for this purpose.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="Servlet1" method="post">

<%List questions = new ArrayList(); // This list has 50 questions

for(int i=1; i<questions.size(); i++)
 { %>
     Question Number: <% out.println(i); %><br><br>

     <%=questions.get(i)%><br><br>

     Answer:
     <input type="hidden" name="question" value="<%=questions.get(i) %>">
     <input type="text" name="answer"> <br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
<% } %>
```

But in Servlet when I use `request.getParameter("answer");` it gives me answer for only the recent question which is displayed, When the user answers some other question..it gets saved as blank (not "null" it get saved as " "-empty space) Also the question is also not getting saved accordingly. But when the user answers the recent question, both the question and answer gets saved..

I think its because some logic error..can anyone help me with a solution...

I want to save the question and answer in the database, whichever questions user answers..

Comment: You would need to uniquely name all `answer` text elements. Also keep single `submit` button for page if all 50 Qs are on same page. One more correction would be closing `input` elements.

Comment: @Aamir: please stop formatting non-code as code in suggested edits. Framework/product/library names are NOT code. Only code is code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the html, each element is identify either by name or id. but it must be unique. 
This code do loop on questions and it's everytime define same name which is `answer` for text input.
so it will not create another one but override previous one text. 
Thus you have to use either `i` else another approach to make it unique like

```
 <input type="text" name="answer<%=i>"> <br><br>
```

you can get at server side like

```
for(int i=1; i<questions.size(); i++)
{
    String answer= request.getParameter("answer"+i)
    //add logic here
}
```

I hope this will help!!

Comment: This is working, but another issue araised..when user enter the answer for 4th question..the database stores blank spaces for first 3 records..i dont want those blank space records..is it possible..?

Comment: @JavaLearner1:  I guess, to answer that , you need to show your db storage logic and `Servlet1` code.

Comment: @JavaLearner1 Might page getting refresh!! does first 3 records answers while u going for 4th question's answer on the page? if not then either u check null condition at server side if answer null then not allow to add but it depends your requirement.

Comment: @bmt i solved the issue, i just wrote another code to delete all the rows where answer field is null. Thank you! your code helped me to solve the core problem

Answer (score 2):

It is because you can not have same name with multiple input type . try appending some alias after your input name Like shwon below:

```
<input type="text" name="answer_<%=i>"> <br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put submit button out side the loop it will send all filed value to your Servelt